# How to compose multiple microservices with WSO2 API MicroGateway

Tags: api, wso2, microservices, api-gateway, wso2-micro-gateway

The new **WSO2 API MicroGateway** 3.0 states as new feature **Support for composing multiple microservices**.I cannot find an **example** of how to do that.
We are trying a use case with just this type of processing:
An API that queries a back-end database using OData and if not found queries another (non OData) API.
In both cases the result must be transformed (reformatted).

Answer (score 1):

Idea of composing microservices, is to expose set of microservices as a single API using microgateway. Basically you can define define set of REST resources and then point them to different microservices. For ex:
/list . -> micro service1
/add -> micro service2.
You can define per resource back ends using swagger (open API) extensions as below
 https://github.com/wso2/product-microgateway/blob/master/samples/per_resource_endpoint.yaml

As of now microgateway does not have out of the box capability to call subsequent endpoints based on the response from the previous endpoint.
But you can transform the response using the response interceptors as explained below link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/MG300/Adding+Interceptors

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Then which WSO2 tool would you advise for this task? Ballerina Integrator?

Comment: you should be able to use the aggregator mediator of either micro integrator (https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/aggregate-Mediator/)
or enterprise integrator (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Aggregate+Mediator)